# cannot connect to fxcm server via api

Tags: python, forex

I get error that i cannot connect to FXCM server. I did look at older threads and it appears that i have the right settings with fxcmpy version at 1.2.6. What else needs to be reconfigured?

```
print(fxcmpy.__version__)
print(socketio.__version__)

1.2.6 
5.0.4 

con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token='hidden', log_level='error', server='real', log_file='log.txt')
```

```
ServerError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a645a1cf535a> in <module>
----> 1 con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token='hidden', log_level='error', server='real', log_file='log.txt')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fxcmpy\fxcmpy.py in __init__(self, access_token, config_file, log_file, log_level, server, proxy_url, proxy_port, proxy_type)
    216             raise ServerError('Can not find FXCM Server.')
    217         elif self.connection_status == 'aborted':
--> 218             raise ServerError('Can not connect to FXCM Server.')
    219 
    220         self.__collect_account_ids__()

ServerError: Can not connect to FXCM Server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the right packages versions are required.

```
>>> import fxcmpy
```

> > > import socketio
> > >
> > > import engineio
> > >
> > > con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token='hidden', log_level='error', server='real', log_file='log.txt')
> > > print(fxcmpy.**version**)
> > > 1.2.6
> > > print(socketio.**version**)
> > > 4.4.0
> > > print("python-engineio version: " + engineio.**version**)
> > > python-engineio version: 3.9.0